# Return the call of a class constructor in a async method, how can I keep it async?

Tags: c#, oop

How can I resolve this?

```
 public async Task<T> SearchUserService<T>(string userId) where T : User
    {
        TableUserModel i = await userRepository.Search(userId);
        return new SpecialUser(i);//SpecialUser is derived from the abstract User class
    }
```

Should I remove the await from the repository search and also make this service not async? Is it safe?

If it isn't and I shouldn't do this, then how can I resolve the fact that my method is not returning a Task?

Comment: Your method _is_ returning a `Task`. Because you use the `async` keyword, the compiler does this implicitly.

Comment: Your problem is nothing to do with async/await. The problem is that you're letting the caller specify that they want to receive *any* possible subclass of `User`, but you're always trying to return a `SpecialUser`. What if they called `ServiceUserService<NotSpecialUser>("")`? They'll still get back a `SpecialUser`.

Comment: You're right @canton7, I just realized it... I just wouldn't like to implement the same method for every User subclass... Would you tell me if it's possible? Is there any pattern that would help me?

Comment: Here's a repro without using any async/await: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAFQAIBlGAQyjAAsBVAZxijqgDcBLMDAA8FAHwAKAAIBGAAxUcnKAElCASioB3ZlxhVqIKhy4BYAFABvC1VtUpAdip4YW2gAcYYfvQA2JqAl1AG4LAF8LCykAZip6YHYMKHowDHsAJmNlKksqCPMYjI8vH39s3PyLIA===

Comment: @FernandoFerreira It would help to learn more about your use-case

Answer (score 2):

At first, we cannot return more derived type if generic type is base type.
Why? Because we do not know how to instantiate properties of derived class. Let me show an example:

```
public class Human
{ }


public class Employee : Human
{
    public DateTime DateHired { get; set; }
}
```

Now we want to assign instance of `Human` to `Employee` variable. But where we do not know `DateHired`. So it is not eligible:

```
Human human = new Human();
Employee employee = human; // compile time error: Cannot 
    // implicitly convert type 'Human' to 'Employee'
```

Now, based on this info we can rewrite our generic method:

```
public async Task<T> SearchUserService<T>(string userId) where T : SpecialUser
{
    TableUserModel tableUserModel = await userRepository.Search(userId);

    return (T)await Task.FromResult(new SpecialUser(tableUserModel));
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to be able to get instances of any derived type from method, then we can combine factory pattern which will return your newly created types.

Factory class:

```
class UserFactory
{
    public User GetInstance(UserType userType, TableUserModel tableUserModel)
    {
        switch (userType)
        {
            case UserType.SpecialUser:
                return new SpecialUser(tableUserModel);
            default:
                return new User();
        }
    }
}
```

and your method:

```
public async Task<T> SearchUserService<T>(string userId) where T : User
{
    TableUserModel tableUserModel = await userRepository.Search(userId);

    UserFactory userFactory = new UserFactory();
    UserType userType = GetUserType();

    return (T)await Task.FromResult(userFactory.GetInstance(userType, tableUserModel));
}
```

and a method which will return type of `User`:

```
private UserType GetUserType()
{
    return UserType.SpecialUser;
}
```

and `UserType`:

```
enum UserType
{
    SpecialUser,
    NotSpecialUser
}
```

Comment: It's fairly clear from OP's code that their `SpecialUser` ctor takes a parameter

Comment: @canton7 ooops, you are right. Please, see my updated answer. I've edited it.

Comment: I don't think that necessarily helps - from the comments, OP is interested in being able to return different sorts of `User`

Comment: @canton7 yeah, I see. I've suggested a class with implementation. Thanks for the comments.